# In powershell, how can I use Rename-Item to output the old and new file names at the same time?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, rename-item-cmdlet

I'd like to select a list of files using `Get-ChildItem` piped to `Rename-Item` and have the output display text with each line showing something like "Renamed *oldfilename* to *newfilename*".

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a bit of a powershell ignoramus, so I'm floundering a little. I've played with Tee-Object and -outvariable and -passthru but to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing and this feels like it should be an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Get-Childitem C:\Temp |
    Foreach-object {
        $OldName = $_.name; 
        $NewName = $_.name -replace 'temp','test'; 
        Rename-Item -Newname $NewName; 
        Write-Output $("Renamed {0} to {1}" -f $OldName,$NewName)
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

One simple solution is to run `rename-item` with `-WhatIf`. This will display something like

```
PS H:\test> gci | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace 'temp','test' } -WhatIf
What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item: H:\test\temp1 Destination: H:\test\test1".
```

Good enough, or do you need it to do it while also doing the operation?

**EDIT**: An even simpler solution, use `-Verbose`. Does the same as the `-WhatIf`, but also performing the operation :)

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd like to get nice formatting on the output if possible. Verbose and what-if work but the output is not very readable. I will up-vote this one though.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
gci . | %{ rename-item -Path $_.fullname -NewName ($_.name + 1); Write-Host "Renamed $($_.fullname) to $($_.name + 1)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I do have a problem with all of them.  This will loop thru all the files and rename them even if the name doesn't change! That's unneeded over-head.

I've add a few more options.

```
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Path "C:\temp" | 
    Foreach-object {
        
        $OldName = $_.name; 
        $NewName = $_.name -replace 'temp','test'; 
        
        If ( $OldName -ne $NewName ){
            Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -Newname $NewName; 
            Write-Output $("Renamed {0} to {1}" -f $OldName,$NewName);
            }
        }
```